# Div continue endless to right

Tags: html, css

I got the following problem.

I have a design similar to this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/k3EUx/

I'd like the div `endless` to continue endless to the right, just like if you are using width 100%. The problem is that there is supposed to be a logo on the left side of it, so I can't use that attribute. Is there any way to do this without just making a really wide div and place it using position absolute?

I need this because the website itself is 1008px wide, but the menu is just continuing to the right, so if you have a big screen (say 1080) this will be expanded automatically.

*(I assume you have to place the div outside the wrapper, but I have no idea where to begin to make this work)*

Comment: Two divs with `float: left` and `float: right` in the same container will __not__ work, floats on both sides are not possible. Simply remove the float property from endless and move menu out of wrapper and it should work (as far as I've understood your problem).

Comment: I tired to move the div out of the wrapper like you said and applied width 100%. The problem is that the logo and the menu will not float side by side. See: http://jsfiddle.net/k3EUx/10/ (@Viruzzo)

Comment: "remove the float property from endless" that part was essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHat you are looking for is a **liquid/fixed layout** (you can google these terms if you want some extra examples).

You can try this kind of CSS:

```
#header
{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#nav
{
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #999;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#content
{
    margin: 0 30px 10px 210px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #999;
}

#footer
{
    clear: both;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Found [here](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/liquid-sample2/)

Comment: I kept reading in your article and found something that worked here: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/liquid-sample2/ . See it for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/k3EUx/11/ . The secret was to have no float on the endless-div and remove the float-right attribute. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad you eventually figured it out. Thanks for posting an updated link in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

What I understood:

You need to have the div id-"endless" so that it covers the whole width of the wrapper.

If I have understood the issue well, you can refer to this: http://jsfiddle.net/k3EUx/6/

Comment: I need the div id `endless` to fill the screen 100% on the right side. If you set width 100% on an element it will fill the whole screen from side to side. I could use that, the problem is that the menu is only on the right-side of the screen, width a logo on the left.

Comment: I am not getting it. You may add an image depicting the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty fix:

```
#endless {
    position: absolute;
    left: 99px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I solved the previous, similar problem I had. I hoped to avoid it this time.